# Laravel 5.4 Take json array of id's

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables.

1. Categories

   `id(int)
   photo_id(int)
   name(string)
   created_ad(datetime)
   updated_at(datetime)`
2. Items

   `id(int)
   category_id(int)
   photo_id(int)
   name(string)
   description(text)
   created_ad(datetime)
   updated_at(datetime)`

**Category model**

```
class Category extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'photo_id'];


    public function photo()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Photo');

    }
}
```

**Items model**

```
class Items extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'category_id', 'photo_id', 'description'
    ];


    public function category()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');

    }


    public function photo()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Photo');

    }
}
```

I want to give items more then one id of category 
if its only one id I know how to display this

`$item->category->name`  (would give me the name of category from category table)

but, if I want more than one how can I do this ?

1. I am trying to take column `category_id` and make it to string type than take all ids in json , its work but than how I display this in view ?
2. I can't make in  database column type json this is mariaDB.

Comment: You have to create a pivot table.

Comment: You defined `belongsTo` relationship, so an item can have just one category, an item can't have many categories in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship to have multiple categories per item. You can think of it as every item can have many categories and every item can have many items.

First you need to create a pivot table `category_item`.

3. category_item

   `category_id
   item_id`

Then add the `belongsToMany` relationship to you `Category` and `Item` models.

**Category model**

```
class Category extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'photo_id'];


    public function photo()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Photo');

    }

    /**
     * The items that belong to the category.
     */
    public function items()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item');

    }
}
```

**Item model**

```
class Item extends Model
{
    //

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'category_id', 'photo_id', 'description'
    ];


   /**
    * The categories that belong to the item.
    */
    public function categories()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');

    }

    public function photo()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Photo');

    }
}
```

You would then do this in your blade template.

```
@foreach ($item->categories as $category){
    {{ $category->name; }}
}
```

Check out the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) for how to save models, it is pretty straight forward.